# Prove that if the graph of a function $f$ is closed and the closure of $f$ is compact implies $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and a function $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $\overline{f(U)}$ is compact and that the graph of $f$ is closed. I want to show that $f$ is then continuous.

From the assumptions, we have that the image of $f$ is compact, so every open covering has a finite covering. How can I use this along with the assumption that the graph of $f$ is closed to show that $f$ is continuous. I'm thinking that I have to show for every closed set $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, the preimage $f^{-1}$ is closed, but I am not sure how to get there.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $x_n \to x$ (all points of $U$). We want to show that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. By compactness, there is a point $y\in \overline{f(U)}$ and a subsequence $f(x_{n_k})\to f(x)$. Then $(x_{n_k},f(x_{n_k}))\to (x,y)$, so $(x,y)$ belongs to the graph of $f$, i.e. $f(x)=y$.

This is not a solution, because I only found a subsequence. Try assuming the conclusion is false, extracting a problematic subsequence, and then applying what is written above to that subsequence.